# T-SQL How do I pull the max value of a record

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm very new to T-SQL so sorry if this is not right.

Using T-SQL, how do I pull the max number from a record using 2 other columns? I have a unique ID number, visit number per ID and then the number of rooms that person have been to (Can do multiple rooms in one visit). How do I get it so that I can only select the row which has the highest number of Rooms a person visits using the persons ID and Visit Number?

Let's say I have this table;

[image]

What I want to have is just the rows with the highest Room number per ID and Visit_No. So with this table I would want to retrieve this dataset;

Dataset Wanted:

[image]

I thought using a ROW_SEQUENCE would work but I have tried but I don't think I am doing it correctly.

Comment: Please do not paste images of code or data please paste in as text only

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Room_No, Visit_No ORDER BY ID DESC)` then filter that result to `1`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `group by` and `max()`:

First get the latest Room_No per ID and Visit No

```
select ID, Visit_No, max(Room_No) as Room_No
from mytable
group by ID, Visit_No
```

Then get the room name using `inner join`

```
select t.*
from mytable t
inner join (
  select ID, Visit_No, max(Room_No) as max_Room_No
  from mytable
  group by ID, Visit_No
) as s on s.ID = t.ID and s.Visit_No = t.Visit_No and s.max_Room_No = t.Room_No
```

Comment: Hi sorry I made a mistake, I forgot to add in the room names too but If i do your query with the room names in my table i get a few hundred extra rows. I have edited the post

Comment: Edited my answer, can you check

Comment: Thank you so much! I have given you an upvote. I best learn about inner joins next!